# How to force the linker to look for a non-decorated name in a lib file?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2017, static-libraries, static-linking

Found no answer for static linking (lib files), but only to DLLs...

I have a static `lib` in which the function I need to call is not decorated (`FT_CreateDeviceInfoList`). But the linker is looking for a decorated name (`_FT_CreateDeviceInfoList@4`).

I can't change the `lib` as it is a 3rd party. I obviously have the header file (`ftd2xx.h`, downloaded [the x64 version](https://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/CDM/CDM%20v2.12.28%20WHQL%20Certified.zip) from [this website](https://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm))

It should build fine with no changes, as I understand it, as it is a 3rd party library provided to the whole world...

What am I missing here? how can I force the linker to look for a non-decorated name?

### Edit:

Silly me... changed the platform to x64 in build option, but now I have another error:

`Error  LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_printf referenced in function "int __cdecl DumpDeviceWithInfo(void *,struct _SP_DEVINFO_DATA *,char const *)" (?DumpDeviceWithInfo@@YAHPEAXPEAU_SP_DEVINFO_DATA@@PEBD@Z)   poc c:\prj\poc\poc\ftd2xx.lib(devcon.obj)   1`

But I don't understand why changing to x64 changes the decoration/mangling option.

Comment: You need to import a header file that declares the _to-be-imported_ function as `extern "C"`.

Comment: @jweyrich I don't understand. I have `#include "../ftdi/ftd2xx.h"` in which I see `#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif`

(and `__cplusplus` is defined)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `FTD2XX_STATIC` define.
If you look at ftd2xx.h header you can see:

```
#elif defined(FTD2XX_STATIC)
// Avoid decorations when linking statically to D2XX.
```

Edit:

Functions declared with `__stdcall` get those decorators in internal names (see http://wyw.dcweb.cn/stdcall.htm). Changing build to x64 changed call convention - `__stdcall` is ignored by the compiler on x64 processor.

For linking error with `__imp_printf` try linking with legacy_stdio_definitions.lib - see [ftd2xx static library link error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46423975/ftd2xx-static-library-link-error)

Comment: Yes, I have `#define FTD2XX_STATIC` just before the `#include "../ftdi/ftd2xx.h"`

Comment: Do you have FTD2XX_EXPORTS defined anywhere? It takes precedence

Comment: No. Made sure `FTD2XX_EXPORTS` ***not defined***.